# R: Trapezoidal integration over the third dimension of an array

Tags: r, arrays, integration, custom-function

EDIT: I changed my example at the end but I'm still stumped.

How can I apply a trapezoidal integration function so that each matrix point is integrated through the 3rd dimension of an array?

I am working with a large array of data (2160, 4320, 46), and I want to use trapezoidal integration over the third dimension of the array (each matrix point down through the 46 stacks of the third dimension). So for example, point 1,1,1 ; 1,1,2 ; 1,1,3 , etc are inputted as the Y points in the integration function.

EDIT: I have been told that this function can be found in CRAN package caTools by Jarek Tuszynski

I have a custom function from my PI for the trapezoidal integration:

```
trapz = function(x, y){
  idx = 2:length(x)
  return (as.double( (x[idx] - x[idx-1]) %*% (y[idx] + y[idx-1])) / 2)
}
```

And I have used apply functions on such arrays before like this:

```
data_output = apply(X = data, MARGIN = 1:2 , FUN = function(k) (mean(na.omit(k))) )
```

But I can't figure out how to get the trapz function to work along the margins that I want.

Working with simple example code, if I create an array like this:

```
x.mat = matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
y.mat = matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
library(abind)
x.array = abind(x.mat,(x.mat+1),(x.mat+2),along = 3, force.array = T)
y.array = abind(y.mat,(y.mat+1),(y.mat+2),along = 3, force.array = T)
apply(MARGIN = 1:2, FUN = trapz, X = x.array, y = y.array)
```

The output is a matrix of the correct dimensions (10,10) but every number is a 4.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That function is from CRAN package [caTools](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=caTools) and its author is Jarek Tuszynski. R is open source but credits must be given (by your PI?).